# Python: Functions and Lists?

Tags: python, list, function

I have a function that, when inputting a list and a specific string in that list, removes any duplicates of that specific string from the list. (`find_start` and `find_end` are separate functions that determine the first and last position of a certain string)

```
def remove_duplicates(sorted_list, item):
    i = 0
    real_list = []
    for x in range(len(sorted_list)-1):
        if(sorted_list[i] == item):
            a = find_start(sorted_list, item)
            b = find_end(sorted_list, item)
            real_list = real_list + [item]
            i = i+(b-a)
        else:
            real_list = real_list + [sorted_list[i]]
        i+=1
    return real_list
```

So for example, `remove_duplicates(['a','a','b','b','c','c'], 'a')` would return `['a','b','b','c','c']`

I'm trying to define another function that uses this function in it for each iteration, like so

```
def remove_all_duplicates(sorted_list):
    i = 0
    list_tru = []
    for x in range(len(sorted_list)):
        list_tru = remove_duplicates(sorted_list, sorted_list[i])
        i+=1
    return list_tru
```

but if I input `remove_all(['a','a','b','b','c','c'])`, it outputs `['a','a','b','b','c']`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're reassigning `list_tru` each time through the loop. Since you're not modifying `sorted_list` during the loop, you're just removing duplicates of the last element.

Comment: In your second case, you want to do `list_tru = sorted_list` and in your for loop `list_tru = remove_duplicates(list_tru, sorted_list[i])`

Comment: Why don't you just test whether `sorted_list[i]` is in `list_tru`, and add it if it's not?

Comment: Is your goal to eliminate duplicates from a list or just to learn how to implement such an algorithm?  If it's the former, consider using `set()`.

Comment: Brian, it's to eliminate all duplicates from a list using `remove_duplicates` (which only removes a specific duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

With every iteration, you just keep going back to the original `sorted_list`. I would recommend copying it and then operating on that copy:

```
def remove_all_duplicates(sorted_list):
    list_tru = sorted_list[:] # copy it
    for x in set(sorted_list): # just use a set
        list_tru = remove_duplicates(list_tru, x) # remove this character from your list
    return list_tru
```

I've also turned the sorted list into a `set` so that you don't try to remove duplicates of the same letter multiple times, and removed the unnecessary `i` counter.

Of course, if all you really want to do is remove the duplicates from a sorted list of strings and you're not attached to the algorithm you're developing, that's particularly simple:

```
new_list = sorted(set(old_list))
```

Comment: This works, but only if the input list is `['a','a','b','b','c','c']`. If I have an input like `['a','b','b','c','c']` it will output `['a','b']` or if I input `['a','b','b','b','c','c']` I get an index error.

Comment: where would I put the `new_list` line?

Comment: @hystehrichal - That line with `new_list =...` can replace all of your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_all_duplicates(L):
    # NOTE: this modifies L IN-PLACE. Tread carefully

    i = 1
    while i<len(L):
        if L[i] == L[i-1]:
            del(L[i])
            continue
        i += 1
```

Usage:

```
In [88]: L = ['a','a','b','b','c','c']

In [89]: remove_all_duplicates(L)

In [90]: L
Out[90]: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_duplicates(sorted_list):
   for item in sorted_list:
       hits = sorted_list.count(item)
       while hits > 1:
           sorted_list.remove(item)
           hits = sorted_list.count(item)
   return sorted_list
print(remove_duplicates(["a","a", "b", "b"]))
```

this is the simplest method I could come up with on the spot uses .count to tell if there are duplicates returns ["a", "b"]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too:

```
A = ['a','a','b','c','c']            #example of input list with duplicates
value = remove_duplicates(A)         #pass the list to the function
print value                          #prints ['a','b','c']

def remove_duplicates(A):
   B = []                            #empty list
   for item in A:
     if item in B:
       pass
     else:
       B.append(item)               #Append the list 
   return B
```

Hope that this helps. Have a nice day.